# Interaction for dummies

Tags: python, paired-data, statsmodels

I used an OLS regression to find correlation between wage gaps and skill similarity in a paired combinations data (ie. A|B, A|C, B|C).

To expand the analysis, I included workplace gender distribution for A, B, C.

I compiled the distribution into dummy form (ie. where Wom >= 50.0)

After a little experimenting, I also compiled the distribution into a similarity measure. (ie. 100 = where distribution is A = B)

I went ahead to construct an variable interaction of a dummy variable and continuous, which looked pretty good to me (ie. where OLS is 'Gap ~ skillSim + Wom:distributionSim')

Question, Is this Ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including interaction terms(s) between continuous and categorical (special case: dummy) variables is common practice in Regression.

Check out https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/interactions-categorical-and-continuous-variables/ for more info